# How to reflect a date stamp log that does not overwrite the one before?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet that I am using to track the status of hiring, where each row is a vacancy's record and one of the cells is a drop down list to change the status of that specific vacancy. Statuses are for example (Advertising, Interviewing, Hired)

What I wanted to do is once I click a status, by the end of the row (let's say last of my record here is Column `S`, so when I click advertising, a date stamp goes on `S` and the status itself gets printed there on Column `T`, and if I choose the 2nd status, it would go on Columns `U` & `V` and so on.

What I used so far is something different, that reflects the date stamp based on the corresponding column of that status:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Long

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("H:H"), Target)
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
  Select Case Rng.Value2
    Case "Not-initiated"
      xOffsetColumn = 100  'Column O
    Case "Adv/Sourcing"
      xOffsetColumn = 9  'Column U
    Case "Interviewing"
      xOffsetColumn = 10  'Column Q
    Case "Offering & Selection"
      xOffsetColumn = 11  'Column R
    Case "Onboarding"
      xOffsetColumn = 12  'Column S
    Case "Contract Signed"
      xOffsetColumn = 13  'Column U
    Case "Joined"
      xOffsetColumn = 14  'Column Q
    Case Else
      xOffsetColumn = 101  'Column T - entry not listed above
  End Select
  Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
  Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a form would do the job, that way you could stick a few buttons which will fill in the timestamp. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been using the below code, but what it does is different, it reflects the date stamp on the corresponding column to the status, I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, you want a Drop Down on each row, around column R, with 3 choices, that when selected will populate the cell 1, 2, or 3 cells to the right, with the current date.

What I would do is this: if I'm going to place a Drop Down on top of cell `R2`, then size it to be exactly the same as the cell* (see bottom of this answer) and hide the Cell Link right underneath it, `$R2`.

Assign a macro, pointing to this sub in a **module**:

```
Sub DropDown2_Change() '(all the drop downs call this sub, on change)

    Dim dd As Shape, ddCell As String, ddValue As String, ddIndex As Integer
    Set dd = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller) 'shape object: the selected DropDown
    ddValue = dd.ControlFormat.List(dd.ControlFormat.ListIndex) 'dropdown's new string value [not used]
    ddCell = dd.ControlFormat.LinkedCell 'range object: the cell linked to the dropdown
    ddIndex = ActiveSheet.Range(ddCell) 'selected index: 1=Advertised,2=Interviewed,3=Hired
    Range(ddCell).Offset(0, ddIndex) = Date 'set date of cell 1,2,or 3 cells to the right

End Sub
```

- Sometimes it can be a pain just getting the Drop Downs to line up with the cells properly (especially if you start moving around columns afterwards) but in the past I found it best to [create & setup the Drop Downs programmatically](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/12/21/working-with-combo-boxes-form-control-using-vba/#create), to ensure perfect alignment, correct naming, etc.  (In fact, any time I *do* need to move them after that, I just delete and re-create them ALL, to save a headache.)

Depending on your needs you might be able to get away with copying the 1st completed, functioning Drop Down manually, and pasting it one by one into each cell below.  Just make sure that the Cell Link is Abs/Rel like **$**B2 or else they all might default to the same Cell Link.

It's okay if they all share the same sub since the code above will check for the Cell Link of the changed Drop Down.

This way you won't have to mess around with `WorkSheet_Change` (which doesn't fire for Drop Down changes anyway).

You can **download the test sheet** I used from JumpShare here: [tmpDropDowns.xlsm](http://jmp.sh/aGc9Z7P). (It views online but VBA won't work unless you download it.)

Let me know if you have any questions!

---

### UPDATE:

To populate first empty cell to the right of the Drop Down with the `Date + Status` (as opposed to populating only columns S,T,U).

Updated Code:

Option Explicit

Sub DropDown2_Change() '(all the drop downs call this sub, on change)

```
Dim dd As Shape, ddCell As String, ddValue As String, ddIndex As Integer
Set dd = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller) 'shape object: the selected DropDown
ddValue = dd.ControlFormat.List(dd.ControlFormat.ListIndex) 'dropdown's new string value
ddCell = dd.ControlFormat.LinkedCell 'range object: the cell linked to the dropdown
ddIndex = ActiveSheet.Range(ddCell) 'selected index: 1=Advertised,2=Interviewed,3=Hired [not used]
FirstEmptyCellToRight(Range(ddCell)) = ddValue & " " & Date 'set date of cell 1,2,or 3 cells to the right
End Sub



Function FirstEmptyCellToRight(cell_In As Range) As Range
    'since ".End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)" wasn't working for me
    'returns cell_In if it's blank, and if not then the first blank cell to the right
    Set FirstEmptyCellToRight = cell_In
    Do Until IsEmpty(FirstEmptyCellToRight) Or FirstEmptyCellToRight.Value = ""
        Set FirstEmptyCellToRight = FirstEmptyCellToRight.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop
End Function
```

---

Adding screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

---

Updated File on JumpShare: [tmpDropDowns.xlsm](http://jmp.sh/aGc9Z7P)
*(Must be downloaded; viewing online won't work with VBA.)*

Comment: Wonderful work there, but I profusely apologize for not clarifying, since what you have provided is what I used to have which I have added in my edit to my question.

Comment: That's okay, even if you no longer need it, someone else might, one day.  Does that mean you have it all figured out now or are you still missing a piece?

Comment: What I need is not to reflect in the corresponding column of the status chosen, what I need is just a date stamp log that keep going forever as long as I keep clicking a status, it would reflect at the end of the row with the name of the status + the date stamp, and if I click again, it would not overwrite, it would reflect next to it and so on, forever.

Comment: oh. That's a simple change from what I gave you. Do you know how you would make the date show in the first empty cell to the right?

Comment: Simple date format would do, similar to the format you included.

Comment: I mean, do you know how to select the first empty cell, or would you like me to show you?  Also Status + Name in the same cell, or 2 cells side by side??

Comment: Well that was frustrating for myself.  Sometimes the "big" stuff turns out to be the easiest part, and the "little stuff" ends up taking longer than it should! The _"first empty cell to the right"_ should have been quick with `.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)`, however it was not cooperating with me, so I used a loop instead.  Should be functioning just like you asked now.  Updated code & link to file above.  Now, I think I've earned the rep I'll get when you **accept** my answer (the checkmark next to my Answer, _hint hint_)  :)  Have fun.  Anything further will probably require a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you have spent on this, I greatly appreciate your efforts. I've checked the attached file, but it doesn't seem to be working for me if I create a drop down list since the sheet does not have one, either way, I'll apply the code to my own sheet and check, I've already accepted your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  You downloaded the file fro Jump Share, right?  (It won't work from the online version since it has VBA.)  The Input Range ("drop down list") is on the other tab.  You can always see where a Drop Down's Input Range is by **right-clicking the Drop Down** and choosing `Format Control'.  The little arrow on the right side of the Input Range box will bring you right to the source.

Comment: I did download it, there must be something wrong as I do not find a drop down list, and even if I add one after the column that has the bullet points of windows features etc, it does not populate the first empty cell to the right of the drop down list.

Comment: @user3078041 -- Hmm, did I upload the wrong file or something?  I added a screen shot above, is that the same file you downloaded from the link??

Comment: Oh man I was going insane, the one you uploaded is different haha.

Comment: Also, looking at the screenshot, if it's not too much to ask, is there a way to have the status and the date on separate cells ?

Comment: Yes, at this point it is very straightforward to split up the Status and Date into 2 cells.  So easy in fact, that you should see if you can figure it out.  I don't mind helping but, you know, "_teach a man to fish..._"  :-)  Your first step is to find where you'd make a change to remove either the Status or Date from the code that populates the cell.  Get that done (and still working), and if you need help for the following step (making it move 2 cells to the right instead of 1 when a Drop Down item is selected), I'll be around!

Comment: Hello ashleedawg, how do I add more rows and have the combo box and have the code reflected on them.

Comment: I figured it out, I am copying rows and pasting, and to have the code reflect, I need to change the cell link, but is there a way to create multiple combo boxes down the sheet in a large volume without resorting to changing the cell link in the format menu manually ?